# Recode variables within a specific range

Tags: r

I have an example dataframe:

```
a <-  c(1:5)
b <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Cat", "Dog")
c <- c("Dog", "Rabbit", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog")
d <- c("Rabbit", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Rabbit")
e <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Cat")
f <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Cat")

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

I want to recode certain variables within this dataframe (for example columns c, d and e).

So far I have:

```
library(car) # Contains recode function
survey[, 3:5]  <- lapply(survey[ , 3:5] , 
                          FUN = function(x) recode(x, "Cat =0; Dog =1; Rabbit"=2)))
```

But this gives an error message.  Could anyone suggest how the function should read?

Also, if I added extra columns before, is it possible to do a range of columns using the first and the last?

i.e. df$c:df$e

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: If you're set on using ``recode`` you need to put Cat, Dog and Rabbit in single quotes: ```..., FUN = function(x) recode(x, "'Cat'=0; 'Dog'=1; 'Rabbit'=2")```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were couple of mistakes in your code. First, there where too much `)` at the end of code. Next, for the `recode()` function levels you are changing should be in `''`. If you add argument `as.factor.result=FALSE` then result will be numeric.

```
df[,3:5]<-sapply(df[ , 3:5] , 
       FUN = function(x) recode(x, "'Cat' =0; 'Dog' =1; 'Rabbit'=2",
                                           as.factor.result=FALSE))
```

Comment: Many thanks @Didzis Elferts If I wanted to reference the columns by name (not a range of columns), how do I go about doing this?  i.e. d and f in the example above?

Comment: Instead of df[,3:5] write df[,c("d","f")]